# How to check if a point lies on polyline in react native

Tags: react-native

I am not able to use `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()` in my react native project.
 Is there any other way to check whether a point lies on a route which I can use to react native?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem while using `react-native-maps`.

You can use `isPointInLine(point, lineStart, lineEnd)` method by using [geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib) JS package. This package has many other useful methods.